# query linear timeline result based on itemevents date ranges and highest priority, help improve existing query

Tags: postgresql

Postgresql 9.1

I need help to improve this query or new ideas how to query results I need.

below is some simple example query which generates a linear timeline ranges of events or call it tasks.
For example, I have a task to wear certain colour tshirts at certain dates or weeks, there are many task and many overlapping, since this summer is really hot, I cant wear multiple shirts same time, can I? :P , so shirts are prioritized by some reason. so what I need is generate simple linear list of tasks I must perform.

```
drop table if exists   temp_box;

create temp table  temp_box(id integer ,event_id integer,event_description text, priority integer , date_from date , date_to  date);
insert into temp_box values(333,1, 'white shirt', 10, '2015-01-01' , '3000-01-01');
insert into temp_box values(333,22, 'green shirt',   8, '2015-01-05' , '2015-01-20');
insert into temp_box values(333,13, 'red shirt',   7, '2015-02-03' , '2015-05-10');
insert into temp_box values(333,2, 'grey shirt',     6, '2015-02-11' , '2015-04-01');
insert into temp_box values(333,104, 'blue blouse', 4, '2015-03-01' , '2015-03-11');
insert into temp_box values(333,6, 'nothing',     2, '2015-04-10' , '2015-04-12');


 WITH days AS (
         SELECT '2015-01-01'::date + aa.aa AS cday
           FROM generate_series(0, 365) aa(aa)
        ), m1 AS (
         SELECT q1.event_id,
            min(q1.cday) AS min,
            max(q1.cday) AS max,
            q1.zz,
            q1.id
           FROM ( SELECT q1_1.event_id,
                    q1_1.cday,
                    q1_1.id,
                    q1_1.row_number,
                    q1_1.lg,
                    sum(
                        CASE
                            WHEN q1_1.lg IS NULL OR q1_1.lg <> q1_1.event_id THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                        END) OVER (PARTITION BY q1_1.id ORDER BY q1_1.cday) AS zz
                   FROM ( SELECT q1_2.event_id,
                            q1_2.cday,
                            q1_2.id,
                            q1_2.row_number,
                            lag(q1_2.event_id) OVER (PARTITION BY q1_2.id ORDER BY q1_2.cday) AS lg
                           FROM ( SELECT temp_box_1.event_id,
                                    days.cday,
                                    temp_box_1.id,
                                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY days.cday, temp_box_1.id ORDER BY temp_box_1.priority) AS row_number
                                   FROM days,
                                    temp_box temp_box_1
                                  WHERE days.cday between temp_box_1.date_from AND temp_box_1.date_to  
                                  ORDER BY days.cday, temp_box_1.id, temp_box_1.priority) q1_2
                          WHERE q1_2.row_number = 1) q1_1) q1
          GROUP BY q1.zz, q1.id, q1.event_id
        )
 SELECT m1.id,
    m1.event_id,
    ((((temp_box.event_description || ' (from '::text) || to_char(m1.min::date, 'yyyy.MM.dd'::text)) || ' to '::text) || to_char(m1.max::date, 'yyyy.MM.dd'::text)) || ')'::text AS info
   FROM m1,
    temp_box
  WHERE m1.event_id = temp_box.event_id
  ORDER BY m1.zz
```

Results:

```
id   event_id      info
333      1         "white shirt (from 2015.01.01 to 2015.01.04)"
333     22         "green shirt (from 2015.01.05 to 2015.01.20)"
333      1         "white shirt (from 2015.01.21 to 2015.02.02)"
333     13         "red shirt (from 2015.02.03 to 2015.02.10)"
333      2         "grey shirt (from 2015.02.11 to 2015.02.28)"
333    104         "blue blouse (from 2015.03.01 to 2015.03.11)"
333      2         "grey shirt (from 2015.03.12 to 2015.04.01)"
333     13         "red shirt (from 2015.04.02 to 2015.04.09)"
333      6         "nothing (from 2015.04.10 to 2015.04.12)"
333     13         "red shirt (from 2015.04.13 to 2015.05.10)"
333      1         "white shirt (from 2015.05.11 to 2016.01.01)"
```

[here query is explain.](http://explain.depesz.com/s/9sc)
In example, query performs fast. it generates data for only one person . 
But since query must calculate data for 50'000 persons in single call. it takes too long, joining all dates and discarding most rows, then running sorts and aggregates ... way too expensive. 
As a terrible amateur as I am now, cant figure out how to do this differently, and cause of poor English, mother Google does not to know what I realy want

There must be simpler and more efficient way to accomplish this.
open for any suggestions, thanks.

2015-07-09:

Execution plan is from sample data, the real query is quite large and to complex to try to post here and reproduce. explain on it wont be no more useful than this examples one. where you can see why its so heavy.

Example is for one "person" field "id" with value 333 represents one persons id. in real case sometimes there would be needed to calculate it for 50000 'People' with uncertain counts of "shirts" per person, so base dataset would  be average like  50000 * 5 = 250000 rows, in secondary dataset joining dates will be 250k * 366 days = 91.5M  rows, and that's just for one year! and then sorting and aggregate on that large dataset is quite slow. memory required for sorting is not the main problem, it still fits in ram.

I guess, I could do "bucketing" or how its called, grouping-aggregating initial dataset by persons generating a custom type of arrays per person, and pass that to function which will do join with dates and do the necessary calculations, this way it will eliminate large memory consumption and overhead caused sorting and aggregating on this large dataset. But that involves creating custom types and functions, which I rather wont do if I can.

I wish there would be some other way to calculate those task-event timeline slices ... without joining all dates and generating needlessly large amount of rows to process...

Comment: Is the execution plan using the real data or your sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit late answer I came up on my own some while ago, better later than never ;) 
After upgrading PostgreSQL to 9.3 version, I had an opportunity and need to 
 try and test range types. Came up with some ideas and revisited old problem with (later improved but still) slow query.

I wrote a function where you pass two arrays as an input value with equal element count. First one is bigint[] with event_id , second one is daterange[] array which contains each tasks active period accordingly. Events priority is implemented based on aggregated data order. So the first task_id in array "takes" - reserves his active daterange from the timeline , second event_id takes and reserves a range or two ranges which where not occupied and taken by the first, third takes whats left available from previous two and so on... 
Function returns bigint event_id and array of ranges each task could acquire...
In the end, using this approach query performed more than 11 times faster with large datasets  reducing execution time from couple minutes to several seconds.

Example Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION a2_daterange_timeline(IN i_id bigint[], IN i_ranges daterange[])
  RETURNS TABLE(id bigint, ranges daterange[]) AS
$BODY$
declare

r record;
base_range daterange; 

unocupied_ranges daterange[];
unocupied_ranges_temp daterange[]; 

target_range daterange;

overlap boolean;
to_right boolean;
to_left boolean;

uno  daterange[];
ocu  daterange[];

iii  integer;

begin 
overlap := false;
to_right := false;
to_left := false;

base_range   := '[''2000-01-01'', ''3000-01-01'']' ::daterange;

unocupied_ranges := array[ base_range ];

FOR r IN SELECT  unnest(i_id) id, unnest(i_ranges) zz
   LOOP
   unocupied_ranges_temp := array[] ::daterange[] ;

   FOR iii IN 1..array_upper( unocupied_ranges,1) LOOP
   target_range :=   r.zz ::daterange;
   overlap  :=     target_range && unocupied_ranges[iii];
   to_right := not target_range &< unocupied_ranges[iii];
   to_left  := not target_range &> unocupied_ranges[iii];

   uno :=case 
   when not overlap then array[unocupied_ranges[iii]] 
   when overlap and not to_right and not to_left then array[ daterange (lower(unocupied_ranges[iii]),lower(target_range),'[)')   ,  daterange (upper(target_range),upper(unocupied_ranges[iii]),'[)')    ]  
   when overlap and     to_right and not to_left then array[ daterange (lower(unocupied_ranges[iii]),lower(target_range),'[)') ]
   when overlap and not to_right and     to_left then array[ daterange (upper(target_range),upper(unocupied_ranges[iii]),'[)') ]  
   when overlap and     to_right and     to_left then array[ ]::daterange[] end ;

   unocupied_ranges_temp:=  array_cat( unocupied_ranges_temp ,uno);

   ocu :=case 
   when not overlap then array[ ] ::daterange[]   
   when overlap and not to_right and not to_left then array[ target_range ]  
   when overlap and     to_right and not to_left then array[ daterange (lower(target_range),upper(unocupied_ranges[iii]),'[)') ]
   when overlap and not to_right and     to_left then array[ daterange (lower(unocupied_ranges[iii]),upper(target_range),'[)') ]    
   when overlap and     to_right and     to_left then array[ unocupied_ranges[iii] ]     end ;

   ranges := ocu;

   if not  ranges = array[]::daterange[] then
   id := r.id;
   return next; 
   end if;

   END LOOP;
    unocupied_ranges :=unocupied_ranges_temp;
END LOOP;
RETURN;

end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE
  COST 100
  ROWS 20;
```

Resulting query:

```
drop table if exists   temp_box;
create temp table  temp_box(person_id integer ,event_id integer,event_description text, priority integer , date_from date , date_to  date);
insert into temp_box values(333,1, 'white shirt', 10, '2015-01-01' , '3000-01-01');
insert into temp_box values(333,22, 'green shirt',   8, '2015-01-05' , '2015-01-20');
insert into temp_box values(333,13, 'red shirt',   7, '2015-02-03' , '2015-05-10');
insert into temp_box values(333,2, 'grey shirt',     6, '2015-02-11' , '2015-04-01');
insert into temp_box values(333,104, 'blue blouse', 4, '2015-03-01' , '2015-03-11');
insert into temp_box values(333,6, 'nothing',     2, '2015-04-10' , '2015-04-12');

with
  a as (select * from temp_box order by person_id,priority) 
  -- ordering by person and event priority 
, b as (select person_id, array_agg(event_id) a, array_agg(daterange(coalesce(date_from,'2000-01-01') , coalesce(date_to,'3000-01-01'),'[]')) b from a temp_box group by person_id ) 
--aggregate events into arrays to pass into function and calculate available dateranges for each event  
, c as (select    (a2_daterange_timeline(a,b)).*  from b )
--calculating data
, d as (select id as r_id, unnest (ranges) as ranges from c) 
--unnesting function results into individual daterange slices
, e as (select *,row_number() over (partition by temp_box.person_id order by ranges) zz from  temp_box left join d on temp_box.event_id = d.r_id where upper(ranges)-1 >= '2015-01-01'  and lower(ranges) < '2015-01-01'::date +365 order by ranges)
-- joining calculated data to an initial dataset and filtering desired period   
select 
  person_id,
     event_id,
    (((( event_description || ' (from '::text) || to_char( lower(ranges) , 'yyyy.MM.dd'::text)) || ' to '::text) || to_char(upper(ranges)-1  , 'yyyy.MM.dd'::text)) || ')'::text AS info
from e
```

This approach with some modifications might be used with other range types. Hope this answer will be helpful to someone else as well.